# Sober topological subspace

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology

Assume $X$ to be a Notherian topological space such that any irreducible closed
subset has a unique generic point. Consider $Y\subseteq X$ as a topological space with the induced topology from $X$. Is it true that any irreducible closed
subset of $Y$ has a unique generic point?

What properties on $Y$ make above question to be true?

Any information even in the case that $X= \text{Spec R}$ with the Zariski topology (R is a Notherian ring) is also useful.

Comment: Open subspaces of sober spaces are sober, as are closed subspaces. In general, not every subspace is sober. See Lemma 1.2.5 in [_Sketches of an elephant_, Part C].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely not: the subspace of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ consisting of nonzero primes, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ with the cofinite topology, is not sober. See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space).

Comment: So if $M$ is not a finitely generated module, we still can not say any thing about being Sober of $Y=\text{Supp}_RM$ as a  topological subspace of $X=\text{Spec} R$.

Comment: Yes, for example the sum of all $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ has support given by the nonzero primes $p$.

Comment: Is this true if $Y$ is an intersection of constructible subsets (i.e. closed sets in the constructible topology)?